# Creating 3D cube using Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I wanted to make 3D cube on my sceen. Unfortunately after combining some code from various sites I am still unable to make cube.

Can someone take a look at my code and advice what am I doing wrong? My idea is to make each face of a cube in different color and everything centered on the screen.

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class Cube {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;  // Buffer for vertex-array
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    private int numFaces = 6;
    private int colorHandle;
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";
    private int MVPMatrixHandle;
    private int positionHandle;
    private final int program;

    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    private float[][] colors = {  // Colors of the 6 faces
            {1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 0. orange
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 1. violet
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 2. green
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 3. blue
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 4. red
            {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}   // 5. yellow
    };

    private float[] vertices = {  // Vertices of the 6 faces
            // FRONT
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            // BACK
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            // LEFT
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front 
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            // RIGHT
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // TOP
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // BOTTOM
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f   // 1. right-bottom-front
    };

    short[] indeces = {
            0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3,
            4, 5, 7, 5, 6, 7,
            8, 9, 11, 9, 10, 11,
            12, 13, 15, 13, 14, 15,
            16, 17, 19, 17, 18, 19,
            20, 21, 23, 21, 22, 23,

    };

    // Constructor - Set up the buffers
    public Cube() {
        // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. An float has 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert from byte to float
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);         // Copy data into buffer
        vertexBuffer.position(0);           // Rewind

        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indeces.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indeces).position(0);

        int vertexShader = StageRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = StageRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
    }

    // Draw the shape
    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        // Render all the faces
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            // Set the color for each of the faces
            colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
            GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, colors[face], 0);
        }

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    }
}
```

Currently I am receiving such outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your indices simply do not match your vertices. Let's just look at the first face. The coordinates of the first 4 vertices are:

```
-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
```

Drawing a sketch of this in the x/y plane, with the indices indicated:

```
2---3
|   |
|   |
|   |
0---1
```

The entries in the index array for the first face are:

```
0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3,
```

Mapping that into the previous figure, these indices define the following two triangles:

```
    3    2---3
   /|     \  |
  / |      \ |
 /  |       \|
0---1        1
```

As you can tell, the two triangles overlap, and do not cover the entire quad. What you need is the following:

```
2---3
|\  |
| \ |
|  \|
0---1
```

So one correct index sequence for this face is:

```
0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3,
```

The first 3 and second 3 indices now match the two triangles. Also note that both of them are enumerated in counter-clockwise direction, which becomes important if you ever enable backface culling. You will need to fix the index sequence in the same way for all other faces.

There's a secondary problem in your code that will prevent the colors from working once you have the indices sorted out:

```
for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
    // Set the color for each of the faces
    colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, colors[face], 0);
}
```

Since you're not drawing anything after setting each uniform value, having a loop here is not useful. At the end, the last value will be set for the color, and the other colors are not used for anything.

To get this working, you will either have to draw only one face (6 indices) at a time, inside this loop. Or you have to introduce a vertex attribute for the colors just like the one you use for the positions.

Answer (score 1):

Since i had the exact same problem, here some more hints for a actual fix.
In addition to the helpful answer from Reto Koradio, i made the following changes:

Inside the `draw` method:

```
// can be moved outside the for loop
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

// Render all the faces
for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
  // Set the color for each of the faces
  GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, colors[face], 0);
  // update the position of the index buffer (6 indices per drawn face)
  indexBuffer.position(face * 6); 
  // draw each face by using the index buffer
  GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct would be:

```
private float[] vertices = {  // Vertices of the 6 faces
        // FRONT
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
        // BACK
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        // LEFT
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
        // RIGHT
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
        // TOP
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        // BOTTOM
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   // 1. right-bottom-front
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   // 1. right-bottom-front
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f  // 4. left-bottom-back
};
```